# Next.js (TypeScript) - Property 'req' does not exist on type 'GetServerSideProps'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I'm working with `next-auth`, and I am trying to access the session from `getServerSideProps`.

For that, I need to pass to it the context request and context response objects, but VScode shows a complaint that these properties don't exist on the context object.

[This is where I see how to use next-auth in getServerSideProps](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#in-getserversideprops). This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import type { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import { authOptions } from "../../pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]";

function EditProfile() {

  return (
    <>
    ....
    </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context: GetServerSideProps) {
  
  const session = await getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions);

  return {
    props: {},
  };
}

export default EditProfile;
```

And the complaints I get are:

```
Property 'req' does not exist on type 'GetServerSideProps<{ [key: string]: any; }, ParsedUrlQuery, PreviewData>'
```

And

```
Property 'res' does not exist on type 'GetServerSideProps<{ [key: string]: any; }, ParsedUrlQuery, PreviewData>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your type declaration as below, because `GetServerSideProps` is the type of the function, meaning its parameter, `context`, and its return value.

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  // ...
  return {
    props: {},
  };
};
```

You are getting those errors because you assumed it was the type of the parameter only.